# How to replace row value without changing the other values in dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am running one python script. I want to change particular row value without changing the other value.
Can you please help me how to do this?

example:

```
df1
Table           Count
case            20
recordtype      50
consumer        70
settlement      150
address         250
bridge          130
```

I ran the process for only 'case' & 'consumer' job. Now new count in case and consumer is 80 & 150 but i am getting the file like this.

```
Table           Count
case            20
recordtype      50
consumer        70
settlement      150
address         250
case            80
consumer        150
```

It is not replacing the count value. It is just adding new column. But i want result like this:

```
df

Table           Count
case            80
recordtype      50
consumer        150
settlement      150
address         250
```

Can you please help me based on the Table name how can i replace the value?

I am using the below code:

```
if(os.path.isfile('/medaff/Scripts/python/count.txt')):
            df_s.to_csv('/medaff/Scripts/python/count.txt',mode='a', sep = '|', index= False, header=False)
else:
            df_s.to_csv('/medaff/Scripts/python/count.txt', sep = '|', index= False)
```

Comment: seems like subject is misleading..please clear things here..what you have and what you are trying to achieve..also `I ran the process for only 'case' & 'consumer' job` ?

Comment: @iamklaus I am running the process based on Active_flg. So i put Active_flg = 'Y' for only case and consumer. So only two job will run means run the sql query and generate the output in dataframe then i will take the count.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue using below code:

```
if(os.path.isfile('/medaff/Scripts/python/count.txt')):
            df_s1 = pd.read_csv('/medaff/Scripts/python/count.txt', delimiter='|')
            for index, row in df_s.iterrows():
                print(row)
                print(row['Master Job Name'])
                print(row['Current_Count'])
                idx1=(df_s1['Master Job Name'] == row['Master Job Name'])

                df_s1.at[idx1, 'Current_Count'] = row['Current_Count']
            set1 = set(list(df_s['Master Job Name'].unique()))
            set2 = set(list(df_s1['Master Job Name'].unique()))
            set1 = list(set1 - set2)

            df_s_new = df_s[df_s['Master Job Name'].isin(set1)]

            df_s1 = df_s1.append(df_s_new)
            df_s1.to_csv('/medaff/Scripts/python/count.txt', sep='|', index=False)

else:
        df_s.to_csv('/medaff/Scripts/python/count.txt', mode='a', sep = '|', index= False)
```